# How to generate a Maven site from Maven plug-in for NetBeans IDE?

Tags: maven-2, netbeans

I use Maven plugin for NetBeans IDE. But i want to know how to generate a Maven site from Maven plug-in in NetBeas IDE ?

What should i set up in order to generate it ? Is there any way ?

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wiki, you can [bind Maven goals to IDE actions](http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices#section-MavenBestPractices-BindingMavenGoalsToIDEActions). To generate the site, try setting **Execute goals** to **mvn clean site** and selecting an appropriate IDE action (for example *clean*).

If you're having problems with the plugin, this might be the problem (from the wiki again).

> The module installation contains an embedded version of Maven for building in the IDE, however it's highly recommended that you use command line Maven for building. The embedded version is not 100% compatible with the latest stable release of Maven. Please refer to Maven website for the latest binaries.

It might be a better option to run Maven as an [external tool](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ExternalTools) and configure it to run **mvn clean site**

Comment: Hi, i have create a CUSTOM action called "Site" according to MavenBestPractices. In execute goals, i have set up "site" goal. So, my custom action appears in project's popup menu under "Custom...". In fact, it is right. But when i click Custom... >> Site, NetBean's output throws Runtime exception. Have you try it ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I don't use Netbeans myself. What is the stacktrace for the exception?

Comment: Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'site'
Scanning for projects...
project-execute
Attempting to resolve a version for plugin: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin using meat-version: LATEST
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.pom
[ERROR] Runtime Exception thrown during execution
[ERROR] null

Comment: What version of maven are you using?  Can you hit rep01.maven.org from your browser.  Are you running on a PC which has a firewall set by a team which doesn't trust Netbeans/Maven to make an HTTP call?